# Best practice regarding repetitive values of database table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have the following `Deductions` table:

```sql
Id   IDENTITY(1,1)
CompanyId  int
PeriodId   int
EmployeeId int
DeductionTypeId int
Amount decimal](12, 2)
```

PK : `Id`

Unique Index: `CompanyId`, `PeriodId`, `EmployeeId`, `DeductionTypeId`

Sample Data:

```
Id  CompanyId  PeriodId  EmployeeId DeductionTypeId  Amount  
1   1000        1        100            1               500
2   1000        1        100            2               200
3   1000        1        100            3               100
4   1000        1        100            4               330
```

Is it a good idea to split this into 2 tables with parent/child relationships?

This is to avoid the repetitive columns `CompanyId`, `PeriodId`, `EmployeeId`.

Table 1: `DeductionHdr`

```
Id  CompanyId  PeriodId  EmployeeId  
1   1000        1        100
```

Table 2: `DeductionDtl`

```
DeductionId DeductionTypeId  Amount  
1               1               500
1               2               200
1               3               100
1               4               330
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the company be within the Employees table?

```
ID EmployeeId PeriodId DeductionTypeId Amount  
1  100        1        1               500
```

It might be handy by having the field Amount as a variable for allowing changes in the future.

Comment: Yes it is ideal to put CompanyId in only one place but I need it for foreign key relationships

Answer (score 0):

if you want best design , parent/child is best solution.

yes i agree.